# Is it possible to use parentclass when it's abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm using capd library (http://capd.ii.uj.edu.pl/) and I have two pieces of code:

```
C0Rect2Set set(ex.start);
timeMap(ex.time, set);
```

and

```
C0HOTripletonSet set(ex.start);
timeMap(ex.time, set);
```

I'd like to abstract on the type of `C0Rect2Set` and `C0HOTripletonSet`. I think that both `C0Rect2Set` and `C0HOTripletonSet` are deriving from `C0Set` (I'm not sure about this, but that class is mentioned in the error if I try to call `timeMap` with argument that is of invalid type).

If I try to use `C0Set` as type

```
C0Rect2Set set(ex.start);
C0Set v = set2;
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ODEs.cpp:136:9: error: cannot declare variable ‘v’ to be of abstract type ‘capd::dynset::C0Set<capd::vectalg::Matrix<capd::filib::Interval<double, (filib::rounding_strategy)1u, (filib::interval_mode)0u>, 0u, 0u> >’
  C0Set v = set2;
```

I also tried to use pointers:

```
C0Set *v = &set2;
IVector i = timeMap(ex.time, *v);
```

But then I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  C0HOSet: cannot move HO-type sets via abstract C0DynSys.
```

One thing that is important is that the behaviour of timeMap function depends on the class of the argument.

I'm no expert on c++, is this even possible what I want to do (unifying those two types)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly, you can call non-virtual methods on an abstract parent class.

However, in this case, your `std::logic_error` is being raised because the capd library doesn't want you to do what you are doing, so the error isn't particularly about what you can or can't do in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> Is it possible to use parent class when it's abstract.

Answer:

It is not possible to create an instance of the parent class. However, you can create pointers to the parent class and references of the parent class as long as the pointers point to an instance of a concrete child class and the references reference an instance of the concrete child class.

Here's a sample of what's OK and what's not OK.

```
struct Base
{
   virtual ~Base() = 0;
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
   virtual ~Derived1(){}
   virtual void foo() {std::cout << "In Derived1::foo()\n";}
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
   virtual ~Derived2(){}
   virtual void foo() {std::cout << "In Derived2::foo()\n";}
};

Base b1;                      // Not OK
Base* bPtr1 = new Derived1;   // OK

Dervied1 d1;
Base b2 = d1;                 // Not OK
Base* bPtr2 = &d1;            // OK

Dervied2 d2;
Base& bRef1 = d2;            // OK
```